# select from varchar2 column with numeric value sometimes gives invalid number error

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I'm trying to understand why, on some systems, I get an invalid number error message when I'm trying to select a value from a varchar2 column while on other systems I don't get the error while doing the exact same thing.

The table is something like this:

```
ID   Column_1  Column_2
 1         V     text
 2         D        1
 3         D        2
 4         D        3
```

and a query:

```
select ID
  from table
 where column_1='D'
   and column_2 = :some_number_value
```

:some_number_value is always numeric but can be null.

We've fixed the query:

```
select ID
  from table
 where column_1='D'
   and column_2 = to_char(:some_number_value)
```

This original query runs fine on most systems but on some systems gives an "invalid number" error. The question is why? Why does it work on most systems and not on some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This dependes on the order in which your conditions are checked. If the condition for `column_1` is evaluated first, then the implicit conversion of `column_2` to a number works. If `column_2` is checked first, then the conversion of `text` to a number fails.

The optimizer decides in which order the conditions are evaluated. If you have an index on `column_2` but not on `column_1` for example, this index is probably going to be used, so the conversion will fail.

---

What do you mean by "some_number_value is always numeric but can be null"? The check for `column_2 = NULL` will return no rows, `NULL` can only be evaluated by using `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`.

Comment: Hi thanks, that explains it. 

The query with the null value should return no rows, thats works correctly this way. Of course we can put in some code so the query won't be executed when :some_number_value is null.